# Multiple histograms in single plot frame

Tags: r, plot

I want to put three histogram plots ([using this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ2qO.jpg)) into single plot:

```
plot(0, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(-10, 10))
abline(v=0)
```

and just the maian plot x axis is scaled. i tried to provide the idea picture by photoshop.

[image: idea picture]

Could anyone help me?

Edit:
Sorry for delay and Thank you for answers.I tried suggested options.

preparing data and functions

```
source("http://www.indiana.edu/~kruschke/DoingBayesianDataAnalysis/Programs/plotPostOLD.R")
download.file("http://www.indiana.edu/~kruschke/DoingBayesianDataAnalysis/Programs/HDIofMCMC.R",destfile = "HDIofMCMC.R")
source("HDIofMCMC.R")
library(fGarch)
library(Runuran)
norm<-rnorm(20000)
snorm<-rsnorm(20000)
repeat{
laplas<-urlaplace(20000, location=0, scale=1, lb = -2.5, ub = 2.5)
if(abs(mean(laplas))<.002 & sd(laplas)<1.05 & sd(laplas)>.95) break()}
```

plot by phoxis suggested option:

```
dev.off()
par (mfrow=c(3,1))
plotPost(norm,xlim = c(-6, 6),xaxt='n')
par(new)
abline(v=0)
plotPost(snorm,xlim = c(-6, 6),xaxt='n')
par(new)
abline(v=0)
plotPost(laplas,xlim = c(-6, 6))
par(new)
abline(v=0)
```

The out put file would be like:
[image]

and if i use split.screen():

```
split.screen(rbind(c(0.1, 0.98,0.1,0.33), c( 0.1, 0.98,0.33, 0.66),c(0.1, 0.98,0.66,0.95)))
screen(1)
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plotPost(norm,xlim = c(-6, 6))
abline(v=0)
screen(2)
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plotPost(laplas,xlim = c(-6, 6),xaxt='n')
abline(v=0)
screen(3)
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plotPost(snorm,xlim = c(-6, 6),xaxt='n')
abline(v=0)
close.screen(all.screens = TRUE)
```

The output would be something like this:
[image]

I also tried user1317221_G suggestion with modification:

```
deeta <- data.frame( value = c(laplas,snorm,norm),
                     HDI1=c(rep(HDIofMCMC(laplas , .95 )[[1]],2000),rep(HDIofMCMC(norm, .95 )[[1]],2000),rep(HDIofMCMC(snorm, .95 )[[1]],2000)),
                     HDI2=c(rep(HDIofMCMC(laplas , .95 )[[2]],2000),rep(HDIofMCMC(norm, .95 )[[2]],2000),rep(HDIofMCMC(snorm, .95 )[[2]],2000)),

type = c(rep("skewed",20000),rep("laplas",20000),
         rep("normal",20000)))
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
gg <-  ggplot(deeta, aes(x=value)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "skyblue",col="white",bins = 50) +
  geom_segment(data=deeta,aes(x=HDI1,xend=HDI2,y=.3,yend=.3),size=1.5)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  facet_grid(type ~.) +        
  theme(
        panel.margin = unit(-0, "lines"),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),panel.grid = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank())
```

And the output:
[image]

Conclusion: user1317221_G's suggestion is more like putting three histogram plots into another plot.
I still seek method to put three histogram plots into single plot by base plot option and not by tricky ways like closing three separate plots to each other and removing borders and etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick way with `ggplot2`, the labelling of the axes is a bit dirty but does the job without invoking `gtable` and `grob` etc.

```
deeta <- data.frame( value = c(sample(10,100, replace = TRUE),
                               sample(20,100, replace = TRUE),
                               sample(5,100, replace = TRUE)
                               ),
                     type = c(rep("skewed",100),rep("laplas",100),
                             rep("normal",100))
                    )
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

gg <-  ggplot(deeta, aes(x=value)) +
 geom_histogram(fill = "lightblue") +
 geom_vline(xintercept = 10) +
 facet_grid(type ~.) +        
 theme(strip.text = element_text(size = rel(3.0), vjust = -4.0),
               panel.margin = unit(-1, "lines"),
               strip.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent")) +
      ylab(paste("normal","laplas","skewed",
           sep = "                          " ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about

`par (mfrow=c(3,1))`

And then call your plot three times?

The `mfrow` describes 3 rows and 1 column (as you have shown in the picture). You can arrange the multiple plots as you wish. A `plot` call will plot the graph on the next sub-plot. If you want to add points in a specific sub-plot, use `lines` or `points` as usual.